# Stop pipeline after 24 hour

Tags: sql, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline in which ingest data from an API and load them into an azure database. The pipeline is called by a trigger. The load time is normally 6 to 7 hours. But sometimes for some reason, the pipeline runs more than 24 hours and on the next day again is executed by the trigger. So I want to stop the pipeline, if pipeline it runs more than 24 hours. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

In Azure Pipeline, set Timeout for agent job would achieve your demand. Each job has a timeout. If the job has not completed in the specified time, the server will cancel the job. It will attempt to signal the agent to stop, and it will mark the job as canceled: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runs?view=azure-devops#timeouts-and-disconnects

Set 1440 minutes for 24 hours.

[image]

Comment: 14_400 minutes is a VERY long day ;)

Comment: 1440, have a good day :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.I have set up what you mentioned and it worked.Appreciate.

Comment: Glad to know my suggestion works. Would appreciate if you mark as answer.